# Swift: UICollectionView into UIViewController. When scroll down collection content to use full view?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have simple `UIViewController` and i want to add one `UILabel` and a `UICollectionView` into same `UIViewController`.

[image]

In the image example i am able only to scroll collection view content into fixed `UICollectionView` area.

What i'm trying to achieve is when i scroll down content into `UICollectionView` the new content to take full page view.

Your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change programmatically the height of an element.
For exemple, you catch the scroll down of your collectionView : with the "scrollViewDidScroll" method.

And when you catch this, you can try to change the height of you collectionView with  : "collectionView.frame.height"